# Deleting Survey Responses All at once in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How do I delete all the survey responses in SharePoint 2007 all at once without having to go through the hassle of deleting one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have MOSS you can use the 'Manage Content and Structure' option in 'Site Actions'.

Open the 'Site Content and Structure Manager', browse to the survey list. Use the select all checkbox on just below the menubar on top of the list to select all the answers. Select in the 'Actions' menu the delete option. Done.

Comment: Thanks @Dribbel for the tip, it works. It was a hassle deleting one at a time.